# About cutoff for quasi-random graphs

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.08564.pdf) by Hermon, Sly and Sousi about mixing time of a random walk on a random graph, there is a concept of $\textit{regeneration edges}$ which I'm trying to understand. This is defined in page 6 as an edge $e=(x,y)$ is a $\textit{regeneration edge}$ if it is crossed, and after it is first crossed the random walk never returns to $x$.

> My question is whether a regeneration edge can be in the loop erasure of the random walk?

For example, if the random walk has edges $(x_1,x_2),(x_2,x_3),(x_3,x_1),(x_1,y),\ldots$ and let the walk never visit vertices $x_1,x_2,x_3$ again, then would $(x_2,x_3)$ be a regeneration edge? By the definition above, $(x_2,x_3)$ appears to be a regeneration edge but then it would be in the loop that gets erased if we look at the loop erased random walk. The paper, subsequently, analyzes the loop erased random walk and so a regeneration edge being in a loop that gets erased is bothering me. Thanks in advance!